# Sound Input or Output does not work connecting to Ubuntu Desktop connected with NoMachine

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, nomachine

I have enabled sound input and output in the NoMachine settings, but I'm not seeing any options for audio output or input in my install of Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (64 bit).

I'm seeing the following hints, I've tried searching but can't find anything that seems to resolve this issue.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was signed in as root, tried creating a non-admin user and it worked straight away.